# nestjs ValidatorConstraint in order, reflect custom validator to swagger definition

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

In nestjs, in order validate query parameter of startDate and endDate

1, sartDate must before endDate, here is custom validator

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isBefore', async: false })
export class IsBeforeConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(propertyValue: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
    console.log('check is before ');

    if (args.object[args.constraints[0]]) {
      return moment(propertyValue) < moment(args.object[args.constraints[0]]);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return `"${args.property}" must be before "${args.constraints[0]}"`;
  }
}
```

2, startDate and endDate must pass in with format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'isRightDateFormat', async: false })
export class DateFormatConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(propertyValue: string) {
    console.log('check format ' + propertyValue);

    return moment(propertyValue, 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid();
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return `"${args.property}" must be with format YYYY-MM-DD`;
  }
}
```

So For startDate, i want first validate format, then validate isBefoer than endDate, I am not able to control validation order as my following code :

```
export class HistoricalQueryDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty()
  @Validate(DateFormatConstraint)
  @Validate(IsBeforeConstraint, ['endDate'])
  startDate: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty()
  endDate: string;
}
```

Also, how to apply the costome validator to swagger definition through Annotation ? 
Only required validation is added to swagger
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set descriptions, and patterns [or any other Swagger Schema Property](https://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject), but there's no way to use class-validator decorators to update your swagger file. They set different metadata for different reasons

Comment: can we control validation order ? I dont want valide "startDate should before endDate" if startDate doesn't have a valid format

Comment: I believe that's actually a problem with using multiple decorators of the same name. Using multiple `@Validate()` decoraotrs means the last one to run (the one furthest down the code) will be the validation that gets run. Decorators only set metadata, the class-validator class reads that metadata and works with it. With using two of the same decorators, the second decorator essentially overwrites the metadata of the first.